# Remove tab indicator in Textmate 2

Tags: editor, textmate, textmate2

In Textmate 2, 
Everytime I typed tab, Indicators(small dot) are showed like this image.

[image]

Can I hide or disalbe it?

Answer (score 0):

In the menu bar; `View` -> `Hide Invisible Characters`.

Comment: no, it doesn't work.-_-a 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9WCcqb3S2bwc1FlOVR4a2tOdmM
 new line character only is toggled.

Comment: For future visitors, yes, it does work, unless your font has visible white space...

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It was font problem. 
The font I use(D2Coding) shows tab character in the Textmate 2. In other editors my font have no problem like that. 
Thank you.